# PHP Change multidimensional array structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello I've multidimensional array that looks like that:

```
array(13890) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Icd"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(111)
      ["nazwa"]=>
      string(6) "DŻUMA"
    }
    ["ProjectIcd"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Icd"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(566)
      ["nazwa"]=>
      string(7) "ŚWINKA"
    }
    ["ProjectIcd"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

An so on.

I want to change it so it looks something like that:

```
array(13890) {
  [0]=> array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(111)
      ["text"]=>
      string(6) "DŻUMA"
    }
```

How is this possible to do?

I want to add, I want to convert the array to json and feed it to select2 js in ajax.

Will that be a problem or not?

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's a simple `foreach` loop to do.

Comment: I'm new to php and looking though internet I coulndn't find answears. Sorry if it's too nooby  question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short solution using `array_map` function:

```
// $arr is your initial array

$new_arr = array_map(function($a){
    return ['id' => $a['Icd']['id'], 'text' => $a['Icd']['nazwa']];
}, $arr);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I got  g.results is undefined in select2 thoug. But it is another question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is something that you want.

```
$res = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $arr) {
       //get keys 
      if (count($arr) > 0) {
         $keys = array_keys($arr);
         // loop through the keys and fetch data of those keys
         // put in array
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            if ($arr[$key]) {
                $res[$i]['id'] = $arr[$key]['id'];
                $res[$i]['text'] = $arr[$key]['nazwa'];
            }
            $i++;
        }
   }
}

print_r($res);
// To change array to json
echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can simple create a new array and add there the values, which you want based on the old array. Then you convert the array to a json string with the php function `json_encode()`:

```
$array = array("text"=>$old_array[0]["Icd"]["nazwa"]);
echo json_encode($array);
```